# *AMP setup Impact on upgrading from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion

Tags: snow-leopard, macos, php

I have Snow Leopard. I want to upgrade to Mountain Lion.
I've setup PHP as mentioned [here](http://latunyj.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/installing-mcrypt-in-mac-os-x-10-6-6/). Will upgrading to Lion affect my PHP setup or any other setup like MySQL for that matter ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the latest version of MAMP it should be fine. MAMP 2.1.1 is compatible with Mountain Lion, although if you have any issues it's pretty easy to reinstall.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading title. I really didn't install MAMP from mamp.info - I referring to Apache, MySQL & PHP manual installations.